# Json.Net Deserialize Dereference

Tags: c#, json.net, deserialization

Say I have some JSON like this:

```
[{"$id": 1, Prop1: true, Prop2: {"$id": 2, Prop2: {"$id": 3, SomeProp: true}}}, {"$ref" : 3}]
```

And I use JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(aboveJson). How can I ensure it deserializes into this:

```
[{Prop1: true}, {SomeProp: true}] //[0] = id1, [1] = id3
```

Instead of this:

```
[{Prop1: true}, null] //[0] = id1, [1] = null because it doesn't match on "$ref" down the hierarchy.
```

Edited for clarity:
How come when I run this code

```
public class StackOverflow
    {
        public bool Prop1 { get; set; }
    }
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string json = @"[{""$id"": ""1"", Prop1: true, Prop2: {""$id"": ""2"", Prop2: {""$id"": ""3"",  Prop1: true}}}, {""$ref"" : ""3""}]";
    dynamic result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<StackOverflow>>(json);

}
```

result[0] is a StackOverflow class. result[1] is null. How do I get it to dereference? What am I missing?

Comment: Find answer here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23505381/json-tree-modifications-that-dont-break-ref-references

Comment: Did you hand-type that JSON?  Because Json.NET requires `"$ref"` and `"$id"` values to be strings, not integers.

Comment: Yeah sorry it's just pseudo code.

Comment: @MaitlandMarshall Please > Post correct/real code > How do you deserialize >   What do you actually get > What did you expected to get ...

Comment: Hi Jim, please see the edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `"ref"` and `"$id"` properties are inserted by Json.NET when reference tracking and preservation is enabled.  For documentation, see See [Preserving Object References](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm).  Thus, to deserialize the original object graph, the setting [`JsonSerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_PreserveReferencesHandling.htm) must be used.

However, even with this setting enabled, your proposed data model doesn't match your JSON.  The formatted JSON is as follows:

```
[
  {
    "$id": "1",
    "Prop1": true,
    "Prop2": {
      "$id": "2",
      "Prop2": {
        "$id": "3",
        "Prop1": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$ref": "3"
  }
]
```

As you can see, the first entry in the array has two properties, one of which is a nested object with another inner nested object.  The second entry in the array is a reference to the innermost nested object from the first entry.  Because of the nested reference, you cannot deserialize to a flat `List<StackOverflow>` like the following:

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public bool Prop1 { get; set; }
}
```

Instead, you need to define a recursive model like the following:

```
public class StackOverflow
{
    public bool? Prop1 { get; set; }
    public StackOverflow Prop2 { get; set; }
}
```

Then your deserialization code would look like:

```
        string json = @"[{""$id"": ""1"", Prop1: true, Prop2: {""$id"": ""2"", Prop2: {""$id"": ""3"",  Prop1: true}}}, {""$ref"" : ""3""}]";

        var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects,
        };
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<StackOverflow []>(json, settings);
```

Sample [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Lo5Bzf).

Now, if we re-serialize **without `PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects`** as follows:

```
        var settingsOut = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented,
            NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
        };
        var jsonWithoutRef = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, settingsOut);

        Console.WriteLine("Re-serialized with PreserveReferencesHandling.None");
        Console.WriteLine(jsonWithoutRef);
```

We see that the innermost instance of `StackOverflow` is correctly placed at the second array location:

```
[
  {
    "Prop1": true,
    "Prop2": {
      "Prop2": {
        "Prop1": true
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Prop1": true
  }
]
```